# site structure and related ajax/php/form requests

Tags: php, ajax

Some background for my case:

Website's folder structure:

```
- assets (folder)
-- js (folder)
-- php (folder)
-- images (folder)
- index.php
- home.php
- other *.php pages
```

Web-page structure:

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<body>
    <p>content</p>
</body>
<? include 'footer.php';?>
```

"header.php" includes "class.user.php", and latter includes "db_connect.php" (both files located in assets/php/). I have ajax calls from my-js.js (located in assets/js/), including to files in assets/php/ folder.

So, my specific questions are:

1. Above page structure is not ideal (both header and footer either include a good bunch of "if-else", or an equally bood bunch of *.css and *.js that may be unnecessary for a particular page.

The structure like proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183163/using-php-include-to-separate-site-content) is ok, but having 2-3 files per actual page seems not necessarily for my case (all I got is 4-5 static pages with other 4-5 ajax-loaded pages). Overall, any advice on some good read/lecutres related to this topic (like udemy or just something good on the internet) are very welcome.

2. Each page starts with:

   session_start ();
   require_once 'class.user.php';
   $user = new USER();

Actually, even when I do ajax call from "my-js.js" to "ajax.php" to save data to db - I have to include those 3 lines in "ajax.php". So, is that necessary or can I make some sort of GLOBAL_PAGE_STARTER to shrink the code?

3. Where is a good boundary between class.user.php and controller.php - say, logged-in user submits a form at home.php - is that a function to be handled by controller.php (which makes sense from mvc standpoint) or for class.user.php (which makes sense cuz this is the function of this class, logically speaking)?

Thank you for any comments, adequate criticism & advise!

Comment: *"can I make some sort of GLOBAL_PAGE_STARTER to shrink the code?"* .. Sure you can, google **"front controller design pattern"**, personally I can't imagine how a web application would be hard to develop without a front controller. Congratulations you came to the point you realized the value of a front controller

Comment: Hey Accountant, thanks for advise! Generally, it's a good direction for me to further look and I am investigating on it now.